# Windows 7/PS2.0 New-Object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection not working, but does work in Windows 10

Tags: powershell

I have successfully used this in Windows 10, and it reports the font family name as expected.

```
$fontFile = '\\px\Rollouts\Misc\Fonts\Arial Narrow\ARIALN.TTF'
$fontCol = [System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection]::new()
$fontCol.AddFontFile($fontFile)
Write-Host "$($fontCol.Families.Name)"
```

However, when I switch to using New-Object, to support Windows 7/PS2, like so

```
$fontFile = '\\px\Rollouts\Misc\Fonts\Arial Narrow\ARIALN.TTF'
$fontCol = New-Object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
$fontCol.AddFontFile($fontFile)
Write-Host "$($fontCol.Families.Name)"
```

It only works in Windows 10. In Windows 7 I don't get an error, but I also don't get a font family name.

But the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) suggest that the class is available all the way back to .NET Framework 1.1. And the Families property is documented as going back that far too. So, am I doing something incorrectly, or missing some evidence somewhere that this isn't workable in Ps2.0, or...?

Interestingly '$fontCol.Families' shows the Name property is there, and properly populated. So, it seems I need to access it differently for Windows 7?

Comment: Property enumeration was introduced in 3.0, so `$anArray.MemberNameOfArrayItems` won't work in 2.0. `Write-Host "$($fontCol.Families|%{$_.Name})"` should work, same with `Write-Host "$($fontCol.Families[0].Name)"`

Comment: That's the little detail I was missing!

Comment: There's always something ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be easy to overlook, your code actually makes use of a feature that was only introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0 - namely *property enumeration*!

`$fontCol.Families` is an *enumerable collection*, so when you do `$fontCol.Families.Name` in PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10, PowerShell goes "`$fontCol.Families` doesn't have that property, but let my try and enumerate the items in the collection and resolve the `Name` value of *those* instead"

But in PowerShell 2.0, the runtime engine simply goes "the collection doesn't have a `Name` property" and the expression evaluates to `$null`.

Given that you're only importing 1 font in your example, you can do:

```bsh
$fontCol.Families[0].Name
```

Or if you want to support multiple fonts in the collection at once, manually enumerate the collection:

```bsh
$fontCol.Families |ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```